# Understanding a probability theory term "deviation"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, standard-deviation

I am asked to find the expected value of the deviation of a random variable $X$, with probability density function. Maybe they mean the expected value of absolute deviation, which  is  $E[|X-\mu|]$, where $\mu=E[X]$. Can you let me know your thoughts?

Comment: I guess since "root mean squared deviation" is $\sqrt{E((X-\mu)^2)}$ and "mean absolute deviation" is $E(|X-\mu|),$ then the "deviation" is $X-\mu$ (or is it $\mu -X$?). In this case the answer is zero. This is just a guess, and it feels weird cause to me, the word "deviation" has a strong connotation of being unsigned (but then again, if it were, why would we need the qualifier "absolute" in MAD?). Really, you should ask whoever asked you the question to give a definition of "deviation".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - if you are generalising like this, then perhaps you should not assume the deviation is from the mean.  There another MAD "[median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)".  And Gauss once wrote about *error medius metuendus* which [I loosely translated](http://www.se16.info/hgb/mode.pdf) as "rms mode deviation"

Comment: @Henry Very true. (In fact I think I flubbed and the robust estimator is the more standard use of the acronym MAD. The one that's based on the mean is usually called mean absolute error.)